# Can I configure asp.net so some responses are serialized as camelCase and some as PascalCase?

Tags: asp.net, .net, jsonserializer, json-serialization, .net-7.0

I have an API with two clients: OldClient and newClient. I currently have this in `Startup.cs` so my json responses are serialized as PascalCase, i.e. as per all my .net objects which have first letter capitalized.

```
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
    {
        // So json output is like 'SomeId' instead of 'someId':
        jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        ...
    }
```

OldClient loves this format. However, newClient would really prefer camelCase.

Is there a way I can configure my app to respond with camelCase for newClient requests and PascalCase for OldClient requests? newClient can send a header to indicate that it wants camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20630) on aspnetcore's github page

The possibility of using specific JSON Serializer Options on a per-controller basis hasn't been implemented yet. It has been moved to ".NET 8 planning", which means it's still a ways-away.

Meanwhile, you could work around this issue by:

1. For data reception and model-binding, you could create a Custom `ModelBinder` by implementing `IModelBinder` interface in a `ModelBinderAttribute` in order to utilize your specific JSON Serialization options. Then, you could simply add the attribute to the endpoints where you need it.
2. For data responses, you could simply use:

   ```
   return new JsonResult([object], [CustomJSONSerializationSettings]);
   ```

It's quite annoying to have to modify these per-endpoint, but it seems like it's the only way until the feature is added in .net 8 (if we're lucky).